# regex, after first word get all character until blank space or enter

Tags: php, regex

hai im newbie as regex i wanna ask something about regex in php
first i have string like this :

```
#HttpOnly_www.xyz.com   FALSE   /   TRUE    1468386389  sessionid IGSC4c9b34af03c4d6a83e9ac949d5f32a6f9a50ced1362b1797cec54ceac3c57110%3Agp888l8neqxFTtJHXMPWkQfIQ9uKv113%3A%7B%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_auth_user_id%22%3A2251871689%2C%22_token%22%3A%222251871689%3ApZdi2i1V6EtoR3p7CgADOomNZLxUta74%3A9d2adf87ebeeb84899dba1a383ef822aeb0a9b7d13c50b6052df407f25c676a2%22%2C%22asns%22%3A%7B%222600%3A3c02%3Ae001%3A1a96%3A28ed%3Ab4b%3Ab8bb%3A2c5f%22%3A17025%2C%22time%22%3A1460610396%7D%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1460610395.854883%2C%22_platform%22%3A4%7D   www.xyz.com FALSE   /   FALSE   1460613989  s_network
```

and my code is like this :

```
$cotext = file_get_contents($cookieFile);
preg_match('/(sessionid)\s[^\S]*/', $cotext, $id);
```

all i want is to get array like this :

```
array [0] => "sessionid"
array [1] => "IGSC4c9b34af03c4d6a83e9ac949d5f32a6f9a50ced1362b1797cec54ceac3c57110%3Agp888l8neqxFTtJHXMPWkQfIQ9uKv113%3A%7B%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_auth_user_id%22%3A2251871689%2C%22_token%22%3A%222251871689%3ApZdi2i1V6EtoR3p7CgADOomNZLxUta74%3A9d2adf87ebeeb84899dba1a383ef822aeb0a9b7d13c50b6052df407f25c676a2%22%2C%22asns%22%3A%7B%222600%3A3c02%3Ae001%3A1a96%3A28ed%3Ab4b%3Ab8bb%3A2c5f%22%3A17025%2C%22time%22%3A1460610396%7D%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1460610395.854883%2C%22_platform%22%3A4%7D"
```

can u guys help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

(As `OP` mentioned in comments that string after `sessionid` always begin with `IGSC`)

```
(sessionid)\s+(IGSC[^\s]+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL3bK1/5)**

**Remember**, `[^\s] -> [\S]`. So you can use any of it as your wish

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/(sessionid)\\s+(IGSC[^\\s]+)/"; 
$str = "#HttpOnly_www.xyz.com   FALSE   /   TRUE    1468386389  sessionid IGSC4c9b34af03c4d6a83e9ac949d5f32a6f9a50ced1362b1797cec54ceac3c57110%3Agp888l8neqxFTtJHXMPWkQfIQ9uKv113%3A%7B%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_auth_user_id%22%3A2251871689%2C%22_token%22%3A%222251871689%3ApZdi2i1V6EtoR3p7CgADOomNZLxUta74%3A9d2adf87ebeeb84899dba1a383ef822aeb0a9b7d13c50b6052df407f25c676a2%22%2C%22asns%22%3A%7B%222600%3A3c02%3Ae001%3A1a96%3A28ed%3Ab4b%3Ab8bb%3A2c5f%22%3A17025%2C%22time%22%3A1460610396%7D%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1460610395.854883%2C%22_platform%22%3A4%7D   www.xyz.com FALSE   /   FALSE   1460613989  s_network"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

Your result is in `matches[1]` and `matches[2]`

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/oEWWjD)**

Comment: wait, why it cant work if i take string from file_get_content "$cotext = file_get_contents($cookieFile);" @rock321987

Comment: @rizkyredjo copy and paste the string on `pastebin` and provide a link

Comment: im not going to take www.xyz.com man. i want to grab is another one of sessionid that grab "IGSC........." @rock321987

Comment: @rizkyredjo that was not specified..Is the second string always beginning with `IGSC`..

Comment: yeah, always with IGSC.. @rock321987

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot man, you save my day.. big hugs @rock321987

Answer (score 2):

Your match pattern string should be
`"/(sessionid)\s(\S*)/"`.

1. because \s matches for space, \S matches for non-space. You shouldn't put ^ before \S.

2. You should add parentheses around \S* if you want to catch the sessionid.

so, `$id` is now

```
    Array
(
    [0] => sessionid IGSC4c9b34af03c4d6a83e9ac949d5f32a6f9a50ced1362b1797cec54ce
ac3c57110%3Agp888l8neqxFTtJHXMPWkQfIQ9uKv113%3A%7B%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_aut
h_user_id%22%3A2251871689%2C%22_token%22%3A%222251871689%3ApZdi2i1V6EtoR3p7CgADO
omNZLxUta74%3A9d2adf87ebeeb84899dba1a383ef822aeb0a9b7d13c50b6052df407f25c676a2%2
2%2C%22asns%22%3A%7B%222600%3A3c02%3Ae001%3A1a96%3A28ed%3Ab4b%3Ab8bb%3A2c5f%22%3
A17025%2C%22time%22%3A1460610396%7D%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.bac
kends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1460610395.854883%
2C%22_platform%22%3A4%7D
    [1] => sessionid
    [2] => IGSC4c9b34af03c4d6a83e9ac949d5f32a6f9a50ced1362b1797cec54ceac3c57110%
3Agp888l8neqxFTtJHXMPWkQfIQ9uKv113%3A%7B%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_auth_user_id%
22%3A2251871689%2C%22_token%22%3A%222251871689%3ApZdi2i1V6EtoR3p7CgADOomNZLxUta7
4%3A9d2adf87ebeeb84899dba1a383ef822aeb0a9b7d13c50b6052df407f25c676a2%22%2C%22asn
s%22%3A%7B%222600%3A3c02%3Ae001%3A1a96%3A28ed%3Ab4b%3Ab8bb%3A2c5f%22%3A17025%2C%
22time%22%3A1460610396%7D%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.Case
InsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1460610395.854883%2C%22_plat
form%22%3A4%7D
)
```

Note that `$id[0]` is the whole matching string, while `$id[1]` and `$id[2]` matches those
parentheses respectively.

Comment: it cant work if i take string from file_get_content "$cotext = file_get_contents($cookieFile);" this link provide you $cotext http://pastebin.com/GbhZShJH @user3846243

Comment: if sessionid is always followed by a space character, use "/(sessionid) (\S*)/"instead. In your cookie file, another sessionid is followed by a tab character which is captured by \s but not what you want. So you can replace \s with ' ', it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 small errors in your regex. First, your second group needs a "(" so that you can access it.
Second, if you use the \S you don't need a ^. So, it will look like this:

```
(sessionid)\s+(\S*)
```

[Here you can test you regex's](https://regex101.com/)